# How to use osquery to check network card name and manufacturer, etc.?

Tags: networking, interface, osquery

I tried the following query but it returns blank for the fields `friendly_name`, `description` and `manufacturer`. Are those fields not supported yet?

```
osqueryi 'select interface, friendly_name, description, manufacturer from interface_details'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code https://github.com/facebook/osquery/blob/master/specs/interface_details.table the columns friendly_name, description, manufacturer are only available on windows. 
Not sure how you can get the information you want, but you can try: `osqueryi 'select * from pci_devices'` and check https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PC/ to what the vendor id and model id maps to.